# Cannot tell where actual error is jsx-a11y linter

Tags: reactjs, eslint

My .eslintrc file looks like this:

```
  "extends": [
    "prettier",
    "prettier/flowtype",
    "prettier/react",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "prettier"
  ],
```

When I start my app I get errors like this:

```
./src/index.js
  Line 1:  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/media-has-caption' was not found                              jsx-a11y/media-has-caption
  Line 1:  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji' was not found                               jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji
  Line 1:  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content' was not found                             jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content
  Line 1:  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/aria-activedescendant-has-tabindex' 
was not found             jsx-a11y/aria-activedescendant-has-tabindex
etc. etc.
```

They all point to line 1 of `src/index.js` which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Line 1 is `import React from 'react'`

I have absolutely no idea where these linting errors are coming from.

Comment: what does `npm ls` tell you?  It could be that the dependancies you are using are not compatible with the version of JSX...

Answer (score 0):

The error message that it is showing is being thrown by `eslint-loader` when it is initializing itself on the first file it is trying to lint (which in your case is entry file `src/index.js`)

This is prolly happening since you don't have the plugin module installed in your `node_modules`

Comment: if you mean `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y` then it is installed for sure

Comment: Can you go into that module and see if the files that it is throwing the error for exist inside the module or not

Comment: I can see the all the exports in `node_modules//eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/lib/main.js` and the files all appear to be in `node_modules//eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/lib/rules`

Comment: See if there is a `recommended.js`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the jsx-ally plugin to your .eslintrc file. As shown below:

```
      "extends": [
        "prettier",
        "prettier/flowtype",
        "prettier/react",
        "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "prettier",
        "jsx-a11y"
      ],
```